# PHP not working in OS X Server

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have a server running OS X 10.8.2. I wanted to install PhpMyAdmin, so I have installed MySQL and PHP (through MacPorts) too. Then I put the PhpMyAdmin folder in the root of my webserver, but when I surf to `http://SERVERADDRESS/PhpMyAdmin` on any web browser on any device I get the source code of the `index.php` file instead of the page loaded (see screenshot). Can you help me please?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It looks like you don't have installed or configured the php module for your web server. One thing is the php cli and another is the web server module.  double check that.

Comment: Your server does not handle PHP files. Have you configured your server to use PHP for *.php files?

Comment: @slash28cu Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @user2747949 Look at the answer of Aspelund. That is exactly what i am referring to.

Answer (score 1):

First, open terminal. In it, write:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Find the row with

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

and remove the comment from the beginning of the line (remove the #). Hit Ctrl+O and then Control+X to save and quit.

Then restart apache:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Then try and reload phpmyadmin.

Comment: The row `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` was not commented out by default...